# Javascript Var and Let Usage

Tags: javascript, arrays, var, let

```
 const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
 for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("I am at index " + index);
  });
}
```

> When I use the "var" keyword in the for loop I get the output

```
I am at index 4
I am at index 4
I am at index 4
I am at index 4
```

> But When I use the "let" keyword in the for loop,

```
 const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
 for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("I am at index " + index);
  });
}

I am at index 0
I am at index 1 
I am at index 2
I am at index 3
```

> Can anyone tell me what's happening here?

Comment: Hello @darshan, this question had been asked before and you may view the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48002533/let-vs-var-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question requires you to understand

- [Hoisting in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)
- [Hoisting Diff in var and let type](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/javascript-hoisting-var-let-const-variables/)
- [Scope Diff in var and let type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var#:~:text=The%20main%20difference%20is%20the,outside%20the%20loop%20for%20example.&text=This%20is%20unlike%20the%20var,function%20regardless%20of%20block%20scope.)
- [Clousures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#:~:text=In%20other%20words%2C%20a%20closure,created%2C%20at%20function%20creation%20time.)

`var` type variable has a `function/script` scope and due to `hoisting` its declaration will move up out of the for loop, so it will come into the `global scope` and on every iteration, it is getting changed and all three closure will share the single variable `i` from the global lexical scope, whereas if we replace `var` with `let` then it will not move outside the for loop being a `block-scoped`, every iteration is a new block and there will be three different lexical scope for three timeout callback and a shared global scope(which has nothing from our code).